# Android Calendar Agenda View Events Getting Overlapped

Tags: android, date, events, calendar

https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView/issues/119

When adding any event to event list using baseCalendar it throws java null pointer exception,
besides after the events are added they all get shown at the same Date ,the date being the date of the last object!

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29772646/28202935-2f535622-6895-11e7-9062-8a40b6d1752d.png

```
private void mockList(List eventList) {

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar startTime1 = calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endTime1 = calendar.getInstance();
    int day,month,year,hour,minute;
    Date date = new Date();


    DateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
    // SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa"); 
    //6/5/2017 12:00:00 AM

    try {
        date =(Date) sdf.parse("7/14/2017 10:00:00 AM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    day=date.getDate();
    month=date.getMonth();
    year=date.getYear();
    hour=date.getHours();
    minute=date.getMinutes(); 
    // startTime1.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day); 
    startTime1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    endTime1 = startTime1;

    eventList.add(new BaseCalendarEvent("First Event: Date 14", "A wonderful 
    journey!", "LOL",
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange_dark), startTime1, 
    endTime1, true));

    try {
        date =(Date) sdf.parse("7/15/2017 5:00:00 AM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    day=date.getDate();
    month=date.getMonth();
    year=date.getYear();
    hour=date.getHours();
    minute=date.getMinutes();
    // startTime1.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    startTime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    endTime1 = startTime1;

    /*
    BaseCalendarEvent event1 = new BaseCalendarEvent("Thibault travels in 
    Iceland", 
    "A wonderful journey!", "Iceland",
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange_dark), startTime1, endTime1, 
    false);
    eventList.add(event1);
    */

    eventList.add(new BaseCalendarEvent("SEcond Event: Date 15", "A wonderful 
    journey!", "LOL",
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange_dark), startTime1, 
    endTime1, true));


    Calendar startTime3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endTime3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,16);
    startTime3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    startTime3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endTime3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    endTime3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    DrawableCalendarEvent event3 = new DrawableCalendarEvent("Visit of Harpa", 
    "", "Dalvík",
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue_dark), startTime3, 
    endTime3, false, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    eventList.add(event3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while adding an event create fresh instances of

```
Calendar startTime1 = calendar.getInstance();
Calendar endTime1 = calendar.getInstance();
```

also catch the exception so that further events are added.